# NHibernate + ASP.NET + Open Session in View + L2Cache

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, second-level-cache, nhibernate-burrow

I am using CodeProject's well known `Open Session in View` to handle NHibernate Sessions. Does it works well with `Level 2 Cache`? Anyone has succeeded doing it? Should I use `NH.Burrow` instead? Any advice on l2 cache in asp.net best practices is appreciated.

Edit: link to CodeProject's article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the Unit of Work pattern to handle my session.  Then I create an HttpModule that implements a "Session Per Web Request" lifetime that works really well.  My HttpModule starts a Unit of Work on the PreExecuteRequestHandler hook, then stores it in the request.  Then it uses the PostExecuteRequestHandler hook to complete the Unit Of Work.

This is the article my Unit of Work is based on:
http://nhforge.org/wikis/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.aspx

Comment: I've been using a very similar approach since that time (when I asked the question) and it works very well, thanks for the link, though.

Answer (score 0):

AS Far as NHibernate L2 cache is concerned, please check this read,

[NCache as L2 cache.](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/nhibernate-l2cache-index.html)

**NCache** is an enterprise level distributed cache for .NET and Java and also provides a fast and reliable storage for ASP.NET and JSP Sessions. NCache also offers its plug-in for Nhibernate secondary level caching.