# Is it considered bad design to pass a repository interface as an argument to a method on a domain class?

Tags: dependency-injection, entity-framework-4.1, domain-driven-design, repository

Our domain model is very anemic right now. Our entities are mostly empty shells, almost purely designed for holding values and navigating to collections.

We are using EF 4.1 code-first ORM, and the design so far has been to shield our novice developers against the dreaded "LINQ to Entities cannot translate blablabla to a store expression" exception when querying against the context during early iterations.

We have various aggregate root repository interfaces over EF. However some blocks of code in the impls seems like they should be the domain's responsibility. As long as the repository interface is declared in the domain, and the impl is in the infrastructure (dependency injected), is it considered bad design to pass a repository interface as an argument to a method on an entity (or other domain) class?

For example, would this be bad?

```
public class EntityAbc {
    public void SaveTo(IEntityAbcRepository repos) {...}
    public void DeleteFrom(IEntityAbcRepository repos) {...}
}
```

What if a particular entity needed access to other aggregate root repositories? Would this be ok or not, and why?

```
public void Save() {
    var abcRepos = DependencyInjector.Current.GetService<IEntityAbcRepository>();
    var xyzRepos = DependencyInjector.Current.GetService<IEntityXyzRepository>();
    // work with repositories
}
```

**Update 1**

I did not mention moving code to an application layer because I consider some of the code that uses IEntityAbcRepository to involve business rule enforcement. The repository impl should be as vanilla as possible, right? Its main responsibility should just be a simple abstraction over the ORM, allowing you to find / add / update / delete entities. Wrong?

Also, this question applies to methods on other non-entity domain classes -- factories, services, whatever pattern may be appropriate. Point being, I'm asking the question about any method on a domain class, not just an entity class. @Eranga, this is one place where you can use constructor injection because factories & services are not part of the ORM.

The application layer could then coordinate flow by injecting a repository impl into its constructor, and passing it as an argument to a domain service or factory. Is this bad practice?

**Update 2**

Adding another clarification here. What if the domain only needs access to the IEntityAbcRepository in order to execute its Find() method(s)? In the example above, the SaveTo and DeleteFrom methods would not invoke any add / update / delete methods on the repository interface.

So far we've combined the find / add / update / delete methods on a single aggregate root repository interface for simplicity. But I suppose there's nothing stopping us from separating them out into 2 interfaces, like so:

1. IEntityAbcReadRepository <-- defines all find method signatures
2. IEntityAbcWriteRepository <-- defines all add / update / delete method sigs

In this case, would it be bad practice to pass IEntityAbcReadRepository as a parameter to a domain method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5223790/235715

Answer (score 6):

Your first approach is better compared to the second approach which uses "Service Locator" pattern. Dependencies are more obvious in the first approach.

Here are some links that explains why "Service Locator" is a bad choice

- [Is it bad to use servicelocation instead of constructor injection
  ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1612034/60108)
- [Singleton Vs ServiceLocator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1328294/60108)
- [Say no to ServiceLocator](http://blog.vuscode.com/malovicn/archive/2009/10/20/say-no-to-servicelocator.aspx)

Both of these solutions stem from the fact that EF does not allow you to use constructor injection. However you can use property injection as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6427891/60108). But that does not guarantee that mandatory dependencies are present.

So your first approach is the better solution.

Comment: Say I had an ORM that could do constructor injection. Would it be offensive to give EntityAbc constructor a dependency on IEntityAbcRepository?

Comment: @olivehour If the dependency is used in a single function of an entity then better to supply it as a method argument otherwise its better have a single point of entry to resolve the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: Yes!

**Long answer**:

Consider creating an AbcService in your application service layer. This service layer sits between your domain and your infrastructure. You can inject as many repositories into AbcService as you want. Then let the service handle SaveTo and DeleteFrom.

SaveTo and DeleteFrom, unless you are saving to and deleting from another entity, i.e. no data access is involved, are methods that sound like they shouldn't be on a domain entity, IMO.

Comment: and if I may vent my frustration without getting flamed, this is yet another example of Microsoft designing a framework that gets in the way of good practice design and forces developers to find work-arounds that fit their bad designs - so much for Magic Unicorn Edition

Comment: you are not alone in your frustration. But what if you need access to the repository to maintain business data integrity? For example, coordinating the internals of an aggregate root's structure or validation against existing data. If I understand correctly, the application layer's responsibility should be to coordinate workflow of domain, and but should know as little about its business internals as possible. To me the code in question seems less like workflow and more like domain knowledge. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Having persistence logic in your domain entities is IMO bad design in the first place. Good separation of concerns should mean that domain/business logic is separated from persistence logic, so your domain classes should be [persistence ignorant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905498/what-are-the-benefits-of-persistence-ignorance).

Previous Entity Framwork versions might not have allowed such a separation but I think most recent versions solved that problem. I'm not that familiar with EF though, so I might be wrong.

With that said, where can you put methods such as Save() and Delete() ?

- If you want to add to/remove your entity from its repository, Repository.Add() and Repository.Remove() are good choices. A repository basically serves as an illusion of an in-memory collection of your entities, so it makes sense for it to behave just like a collection or a list with the appropriate methods.
- If you want to persist changes made to an existing entity, there are other ways to do that. You could have a Repository.Save() method but [some](http://codebetter.com/iancooper/2011/04/12/repository-saveupdate-is-a-smell/) [consider](http://richarddingwall.name/2009/10/22/repositories-dont-have-save-methods/) it bad practice. Oftentimes the changes are part of a higher level operation handled in a transaction-like context such as a Unit of Work, in that case you can let the operation persist all the objects in its scope when it finishes. For instance, if you use an [Open Session in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223398/nhibernate-asp-net-open-session-in-view-l2cache) approach for your web application, changes are automatically persisted when the request ends.
  Or you can rely on an ad-hoc call of your ORM's Save() method for your particular entity which hopefully shouldn't be grafted onto the entity code itself (with NHibernate, for instance, it's available at runtime on the proxied entity).

[Update]

Putting that in perspective with your subsequent questions (though I'm not sure I understand all of them well) :

- I see no value in splitting your repository into a ReadRepository and a WriteRepository. In DDD, a repository's responsibility is clearly to provide a collection to query from *as well as* add to or remove from. It's still quite cohesive that way.
- It's not an entity's responsibility to fiddle with its own persistence, so it shouldn't be aware of its own repository for that precise purpose. Otherwise, it's pretty rare that an entity rightfully needs to have knowledge of its own repository (usually it means that the entity has a relationship to another entity of the same type, like parent/child, and you want to get the other entity from the repository)
- However, entities and other domain objects obviously do need to obtain references to other entities at times. In that case, try to get these references through traversal of other objects within the boundary of your aggregate first before looking for a repository. If you absolutely need a repository to get the object you want, it's a good idea to inject the repository through any flavour of injection you like. As Eranga pointed out, service locator might turn out to be a sub-par dependency injection ersatz though.

  Last thing, the kind of injection you mentioned - SaveTo(IEntityAbcRepository repos) - is peculiar because it is neither constructor nor setter injection, but rather an ephemeral injection lasting just the time of a method. It implies that whoever calls your method must know what repository to pass at that precise moment, which is not obvious. It might be useful, but I'd say it's not the form of injection you would typically mainly use.

Comment: we do wrap EF DbContext in an IUnitOfWork interface. The domain code would not contain any gory persistence details, as far as calling SaveChanges() on IUnitOfWork or anything like that. However, consider that before being saved, an entity's internal structure needs to be checked and possibly altered. These checks might require executing Find() method(s) on the repository (not add / update / delete). Perhaps we should separate our Find() methods onto a different repository interface than the add / update / delete? Something like IEntityAbcReadRepository and IEntityAbcWriteRepository?

Comment: Ok let's have some code. Give us the gory details. It's easier to discuss stuff like this after seeing the code.